# Dropdown is not working in reactJS Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-4

I am using reactJS with Bottstrap. I am trying to put user image and with drodown. so when user click on dropdown the the dropdown will open.

My dropdown is not working.

Here is my code. :

```
    <div class="dropdown">
   <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="nav-item nav-link dropdown-toggle user-action">
   <img class = "loginImage" src="https://someImage" class="bi bi-person" alt="Avatar"></img>
   </a> 
   <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li>
         <a href="#" class="dropdown-item"> Profile A</a>
      </li>
      <li>
         <a href="#" class="dropdown-item"> Profile B</a>
      </li>
      <li>
         <a href="#" class="dropdown-item"> Profile C</a>
      </li>
      <li>
         <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Profile D</a>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Any help here or any other way to implement this.

My Dependency :

```
    "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.35",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.15.3",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.14",
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.9.2",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.13.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "bootstrap": "^5.0.1",
    "bootstrap-icons": "^1.5.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-popper": "^2.2.5",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.2"
  },
```

Comment: did you add jquery as dependency?

Comment: let me upload my packgae json

Comment: @Apostolos NO. I haven't

Comment: @Apostolos one quixk questio, how u sure that this code is from version 3. Because i am using code from bootstrap 5 only from this page. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/dropdowns/

Comment: check my answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order for the dropdown to work with bootstrap, you need to import `@popperjs/core` dependency.

bootsrap 5 has dropped dep on jquery so there is no need anymore to import `jquery`

Check my [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-boyd-51c60)

Comment: Nope no luck for me even after adding `@popperjs/core`

Comment: you need to import bootstrap and popper. check the sandbox and the imports.

Comment: `import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import "@popperjs/core";
import "bootstrap";`

Comment: I have run this command in my terminal `npm i react-popper @popperjs/core` I have updated the dependency in question. correct me if i m wrong. I m new in reactJS

Comment: use these imports in your js file and try again.

Comment: no need for react-popper. just `@popperjs/core`

Comment: Nope. I will come to this part later. Imoved to other stuff.

Comment: It is working if i use in seperate class, now i have change the coponent type it self. thanks for the answer. Do u have any suggestion how can i show image dropdown for profile thing on navbar in react. thanks @Apostolos

Comment: didnt quite understand. you mean to add an image instead of text? you can easily add an iomage of height e.g. 40px and then apply the equivalent css to remove the background from the container div

Comment: Will try that. Thanks.